# onClick does not trigger in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React but I just can't get this onClick to trigger a simple event. What am I doing wrong?

```jsx
React.createClass({
  onOptionSelect: function() { 
    console.log("WHY");
  },

  render: function () {
    var className = "option-item "+this.props.className;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={className} onClick={this.onOptionSelect}>
          <h6>{this.props.text}</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/b7jszded/ .

Comment: That's so weird, wtf lol...

Comment: I get this error in console. Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string

Comment: The code you posted here does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was another component on the page that had a string passed into onClick. As soon as that was fixed, the debug error went away and all onClick functions of all components worked